# Error bars (confidence intervals) in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Error bars (or confidence intervals)are not currently supported in Highcharts but someone edited an existing module as a workaraound. The results are shown in this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b74Tt/

However, what if I have more than one series that needs to have error bars? How can one ErrorBar series be tied to a specific column series (and therefore be displayed exactly on top of it)? My problem is shown here in this other jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FaYdK/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new type of chart based on the column one. What I get is thin columns that act as error bars. I also used the events > legendItemClick to create a small function that hides the next series (the Error bar) when a column is clicked, so that its corresponding error bar also hides or displays.

See the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/FaYdK/3/

I'm pretty satisfied with the solution, the only thing is that I would like the error bars to be displayed in the usual form (an inverted H) instead of a single line (thin rectangle). If anyone knows how to do this, please comment!